# Does Wubi contain UNR?

Tags: netbook, wubi, ubuntu-netbook-remix

I'd like to avoid the repartitioning that's required when installing Ubuntu "for real". 
[Wubi](http://wubi-installer.org/) is the perfect answer because it just goes inside the Windows partition that's already there.

I know that Wubi contains Ubuntu, and Mythbuntu, and some other variants.
But does it also contain [Ubuntu Netbook Remix](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UNR)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you grab `wubi.exe` [from the Wubi site](http://wubi-installer.org/), you can choose the Netbook Remix as the Desktop Environment to be installed (it's the second option in the Desktop Environment dropdown).

Alternately, you can install the default Ubuntu via Wubi, and add UNR to your installation later by installing the [*ubuntu-netbook-remix* meta package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/ubuntu-netbook-remix) via Synaptic or Aptitude.  That will pull in all the additional packages that make up UNR.

Comment: Great, thanks for the speedy answer. I didn't want to install it just to find out if UNR was available. You saved me some hours there :-)